# Angular 5 async-await not waiting as expected

Tags: angular, asynchronous, async-await

I have a need to create a "synchronous" http call in Angular 5. Given the below code snippets:

```
console.log("1) Before async-await call");
this.setJwtToken();
console.log("3) After async-await call");
```

and

```
async setJwtToken(): Promise<any>  {
    var result = await this.http.get<any>(URL,{}).toPromise();
    console.log("2) getJwtToken complete: ", result);
    return result;
}
```

I would expect my console log messages to print as follows:

1) Before async-await call
2) getJwtToken complete: "result here"
3) Before async-await call

But the order I'm getting is:

1) Before async-await call
3) Before async-await call
2) getJwtToken complete: "result here"

I'm a bit at a loss as to why the code is not waiting for the http call to complete before continuing.  This is my first attempt at using async-await in Angular so if anyone has any ideas on what might be missing it would be greating appreciated.

Comment: `await this.setJwtToken();` will give you your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [comment added by Lexith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029977/angular-5-async-await-not-waiting-as-expected/56173403#comment98703590_56029977) helped :-)

> `await this.setJwtToken();` will give you your expected output.